# Appending to an array within a ForEach-Object loop

Tags: powershell, scripting

I've run into a strange problem when attempting to append to an array from within a ForEach-Object loop that is traversing another array.

I have attempted to recreate the problem as concisely as I can:

```
$InputObject1 = @{
    Property = '123456';
}

$InputObject2 = @{
    Property = '654321';
}

$InputArray = $InputObject1, $InputObject2


$OutputObject = @{
    TargetArray = '';
} 

$InputArray | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output $_.property
    $OutputObject.TargetArray += $_.property
}

Write-Output "Testing Array Readback" 
Write-Output $OutputObject.TargetArray[0]
Write-Output $OutputObject.TargetArray[1]
```

The output I get is:

```
123456
654321
TESTING Array Readback
1
2
```

However, the output I'm *trying* to achieve is:

```
123456
654321
TESTING Array Readback
123456
654321
```

For some reason, even though the value of **$_.property** is different in each iteration of the loop; The value that is written to the **$OutputObject.TargetArray** almost appears to be traversing the value of the first iteration in some strange recursive manner.

I'm still quite new to PowerShell scripting so my apologies if I've made a really obvious mistake or assumption somewhere. This one has completely stumped me. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:** Solution found.

Thanks to the input from @LotPings, I figured out what the problem was. My definition of **TargetArray** within **$OutputObject** was incorrect.

I had incorrectly written:

```
$OutputObject = @{
    TargetArray = '';
}
```

Which means the line:

```
$OutputObject.TargetArray += $_.property
```

... is actually concatenating the two values together resulting in '123456654321'. As opposed to adding a value to the array like {123456, 654321}.

The **$OutputObject** Hash Table should therefore be defined as:

```
$OutputObject = @{
    TargetArray = @();
}
```

This results in the desired output.

Comment: The output hashtable should be defined as `@{ TargetArray = $InputArray.Property }` and no loop. Any time you see `+=` in PowerShell you should think "this is a bad way to do it, it's taking more code and running more slowly"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$InputArray` and `$OutputObject` are both hashtables,
look what they contain:

```
> $InputArray

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Property                       123456
Property                       654321
```

---

```
> $OutputObject

Name                           Value
----                           -----
TargetArray                    123456654321
```

And think about how this could happen.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I see where the mistake is now. I needed to define TargetArray using @() to indicate it was an empty array as opposed to setting it to a blank value. I'll edit the post to include the corrected script. Thanks again!